# regular representation and class function

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose we have a left regular representation $f$ for group $G$. Let $\alpha$ be a complex map from $G$ to $C$. Now if $\phi=\Sigma_{g\in G} \alpha(g)f(g)$ is g-homomorphism, then $\alpha$ is a class function,i.e. $\alpha$ is constant on conjugacy classes of $G$.

Let $V$ be the representation space. Since $\phi$　is $g$ homomorphis, $\phi(hv)=h\phi(v)$ $v\in V$ and $h\in G$ (we use group element to represent group action).Then we have $\Sigma \alpha(g)ghv=\Sigma h\alpha(g)gv$. I think we should pick some special $v$ to derive the result. But I don't know how to pick a proper $v$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\phi(h), h \in G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with your obsvertation: if $\phi$ is a $G$-homomorphism, then for any $v$,

$$ \sum_g \alpha(g) \, gh (v) = \sum_g \alpha(g) \, hg(v) $$

Now let's re-index the left-hand sum. Since conjugation by $h$ (i.e. $x \mapsto hxh^{-1}$) is a group automorphism, it permutes the elements of the group around. That means if we replace $g$ by $hgh^{-1}$ everywhere in the sum, it will still be summing over all the group elements, just in a different order. Making this substitution, the equation becomes:

$$ \sum_g \alpha(hgh^{-1}) \, hg (v) = \sum_g \alpha(g) \, hg(v) $$

Subtracting everything to one side gives:

$$ 0 = \sum_g \left( \alpha(g) - \alpha(hgh^{-1}) \right) \, hg(v) $$

Now we need to recall that this is the regular representation. That means that as $g$ ranges over $G$, the vectors $g(v)$ are all linearly independent. And if $g$ ranges over $G$, then $hg$ also ranges over $G$, since the map $g \mapsto hg$ is a group automorphism. So all $hg(v)$ are linearly independent. Thus all the coefficients must be zero, meaning $\alpha$ is a class function.

Comment: State clearly that $\phi(h)v = \sum_g \alpha(g) f(gh)v$. Then multiply by $f(h^{-1})$ and let $v = e_1$ so that $f(g)v= e_g$.